# SQL Server certificate and symmetric key

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-express

I had the need to encrypt/decrypt some personal information in my database such as credit card no and passwords.

Following the steps from Microsoft I was successfully encrypt & decrypt the data.

But after some test I have questions.

Assume someone gets unauthorized access to the database (hack) and can see the database in SSMS from his own computer. Surly he can see that I had some certificate and symmetric key setup.

In order to display the  data the examples shows the following query

```
OPEN symmetric KEY symmetrickey1 
decryption BY certificate certificate1
Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID  
SELECT customer_id, 
   credit_card_number_encrypt                                 AS 
   'Encrypted Credit Card Number', 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, Decryptbykey(credit_card_number_encrypt)) AS 
   'Decrypted Credit Card Number' 
FROM   dbo.customer_data; 
-- Close the symmetric key 
CLOSE symmetric KEY symmetrickey1;
```

If the above query returns the data and can see the credit card how can then be protected? Shouldn't it be necessary to pass a password somewhere in the query?

I am sure that I miss something here. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: sorry i was talking for SQL Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to include a password to the cerificate

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate1
Encryption By Password='Password123'
WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect Data'
```

for retrieving data

```
OPEN Symmetric KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1 With Password='Password123'
;
select *,CONVERT(nvarchar(255),DECRYPTBYKEY(Credit_Card_No)) as
[Credit_Card_No3] from Customers
;
Close Symmetric Key SymmetricKey1
```